# How to find all indexes of arrays having a certain value with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In the following example code, how can I find all the indexes of any array of year 2021 in the dates?   Thank you for any guide!

```
function test() {
  const dates = [
    'October 31, 2020',
    'November 30, 2020',
    'December 31, 2020',
    'January 31, 2021',
    'February 28, 2021',
    'March 31, 2021',
  ];


  // How should the following code be changed to get indexes of any array of year 2021, which should be 3,4,5?
  // The following code returned only the first array index, 3, not 3,4,5.
  var indexes = dates.findIndex(el => el.includes('2021'));
  console.log(indexes);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/
function test() {
  const dates = [
'October 31, 2020',
'November 30, 2020',
'December 31, 2020',
'January 31, 2021',
'February 28, 2021',
'March 31, 2021',
  ];


  // The following code returned 3,4,5.
  var indexes = dates.reduce((acc,el,i) => el.includes('2021') ? [...acc,i] : acc,[]);
  console.log(indexes);
}
test()
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  But it returns [ 'January 31, 2021', 'February 28, 2021', 'March 31, 2021' ], not the index of those arrays.   What I want is the index of those arrays.   Any different approach?

Comment: @Newbie answer edited